# How to run rospy.spin() and Tkinter.mainloop() at the same time?

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to learn ROS by writing a really simple group-chat program in Python 2.7, Tkinter and ROS Kinetic.

I built a simple GUI on Tkinter that will publish the Entry's value to the topic when the user presses Enter.

I am stuck on this issue, where I need to run both rospy.spin() in order to subscribe to the topic, and Tkinter.mainloop(), in order for the GUI to work.

May I know how do I run both at the same time? From what I understand they each halt the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import Tkinter as tk
from std_msgs.msg import String

def send(event):
        pub = rospy.Publisher("chat", String, queue_size=10)
        rospy.loginfo("attempting to send: " + entry_field.get())
        pub.publish(entry_field.get())
        entry_field.delete(0, "end")

def receive(msg):
        rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        rospy.init_node("chat", anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber("lets_talk", String, receive)

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Let's chat!")

        msg_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        msg_frame.pack()

        msg_list = tk.Listbox(msg_frame, height=30, width=100)
        msg_list.pack()

        entry_field = tk.Entry(root)
        entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
        entry_field.pack()

        tk.mainloop()
        rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301729/how-to-run-rospy.spin()-and-tkinter.mainloop()-at-the-same-time?/) by [avalice](https://answers.ros.org/users/37200/avalice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am stuck on this issue, where I need to run both rospy.spin() in order to subscribe to the topic, and Tkinter.mainloop(), in order for the GUI to work.

> May I know how do I run both at the same time?

This has a really short answer: you don't.

See #q106781 for some explanation.

Summary: `rospy.spin()` doesn't do much more than sleeping ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/fb6a6bd2839206ab99994a0d0beb89a6ffab1223/clients/rospy/src/rospy/client.py#L118-L132)). In `roscpp`, things are different, see some of the other Q&As on this site for that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avalice](https://answers.ros.org/users/37200/avalice/) on 2018-08-27**:
Thank you! That solved my issue!

**Comment by [basb1](https://answers.ros.org/users/39975/basb1/) on 2019-02-12**:
@avalice i am having the same trouble like you had, could you share how you where able to publish topics based on tkinter inputs?